# Retrofit 2: Handling dynamic JSON response

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit2

I am using `retrofit 2` as a REST client and I cannot figure out how to deserialise a `dynamic JSON response`.

Depending on the status value (success or failure), our JSON can have two different objects in the `result` field:

1. A successful response returns a `User` object:

   ```
   {
      "status": 200,
      "message": "OK",
      "result": {
         "id": "1",
         "email": "bla@bla.bla"
          ...
      }
   }
   ```
2. A failed response returns an `Error` object:

   ```
   {
      "status": 100,
      "message": "FAILED",
      "result": {
         "error": "a user with this account email address already exists"
      }
   }
   ```

I have created 3 `POJO` classes...

1. APIResponse:

   ```
   public class APIResponse<T> {
       @Expose private int status;
       @Expose private String message;
       @Expose private T result;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. User:

   ```
   public class User {
       @Expose private String id;
       @Expose private String email;
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Error:

   ```
   public class Error {
       @Expose private String error;
       ...
   }
   ```

Here is how I make the call:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT(LOGIN)
Call<APIResponse<User>> login(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
```

And here is how I get a response:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<APIResponse<User>> call, Response<APIResponse<User>> response) {
   ...
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<APIResponse<User>> call, Throwable t) {
   ...
}
```

**Question:**

The `API call` expects a return type of `Call<APIReponse<User>>`. However, it might not get a `User` object back... So how do I modify this approach to accept either `APIResponse<User>` or `APIResponse<Error>`.

In other words, how do I deserialise JSON data that can be in two different formats?

**Solutions I have looked at:**

1. Including 'error' field in User class or extending Error class (ugly).
2. Custom interceptor or converter (struggled to understand).
3. Convince API devs to change it and make my life easier :)

Comment: why cant you try using volley

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the solution is viable, but you can try changing `<APIResponse<User>>` to `<APIResponse<Object>>`

```
Call<APIResponse<Object>> login(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);

@Override
   public void onResponse(Call<APIResponse<Object>> call, Response<APIResponse<Object>> response) {
   //depending on the response status, you can cast the object to appropriate class
   Error e = (Error)response.body().getResult();
   //or
   User u = (User)response.body().getResult();
}
```

or another alternative, use String instead of POJO

```
Call<String> login(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
```

retrieve the JSON and serialize manually or use GSON

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is similar to what we are currently doing, but I was hoping to find a more elegant way. It seems like the JSON structure needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the response code and use the desired class to process the json